# Changing position of cursor in Turtle after drawing a shape causes the shape to be moved even though pen up routine called

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

I wrote a simple test program to draw a circle, create a custom shape (an arrow), draw the arrow in the circle at a 45 degree angle and then draw two lines of text on the screen. The code performed as expected until I added code to reposition the screen cursor (using the setpos method) and then write two lines of text on the screen.  After adding the code to write the text, the arrow shape is moved to the new position of the first line of text while the circle remains in place!!

It appears that once the shape is drawn, all of the methods following the call to the draw shape method ('shape') continue to operate on that shape (graphical object)!!  There does not appear to be a Turtle method that redirects methods to operate on a different graphical object.

[image: The screen without displaying any text.]

[image: The screen when displaying text.]

The code used to produce these screen shots is shown below:

```
import turtle as tg
from turtle import Shape, register_shape, shape
# Create an arrow shape:
shArrow=Shape ("compound")
polyShaft = \
    ((-5, -95),(-5, 75),(5, 75),(5, -95),(-5, -95))
polyPoint = \
    ((-5, 75),(-10, 75),(0, 95),(10, 75),(5, 75))
shArrow.addcomponent (polyShaft, "black","black")
shArrow.addcomponent (polyPoint, "black","black")
register_shape ("Arrow", shArrow)
# Draw a circle and fill it with red color:`your text`
tg.fillcolor("red")
tg.begin_fill ()
tg.speed (0)
tg.pu ()
tg.setpos (200, y=0)
tg.begin_fill ()
tg.pd ()
tg.circle (100,steps=256)
tg.end_fill ()
tg.pu ()
# Draw the arrow at a 45 degree angle:
tg.setpos (200, y=100)
tg.pd ()
tg.shape ("Arrow")
tg.tiltangle (45)
tg.pu ()
# Display the outside temperature:
tg.goto (-300, y=200)
tg.pd ()
tg.write ("OUTSIDE TEMPERATURE: 68.1 F", font=('Arial', 12, 'normal'))
tg.pu ()
# Display the outside humidity:
tg.setpos (-300, y=180)
tg.pd ()
tg.write ("OUTSIDE HUMIDITY:    88.1%", font=('Arial', 12, 'normal'))
```

First, I commented out all of the code following the penup call after the arrow shape was drawn.  The resulting display is what I expected, a red circle with an arrow at a 45 degree angle.  Next, I uncommented the code that writes text on the screen and replaced the setpos call with a call to goto.  The result is that the arrow moves to the position of the first line of text!

Comment: `shape()` isn't a drawing command, not in the same sense that `circle()` or `write()` is, or `goto()` with the pen down.  Instead, it *specifies what the turtle looks like*, so the shape will appear in whatever position and rotation the turtle is moved to.  You can use `stamp()` to make a fixed copy of the turtle shape, or use drawing commands to draw your arrow at a desired position.

Comment: Jason, thank you very much for your excellent comment.  Being a NOOB, I didn't grasp the fact that  the shape function changes the shape of the turtle from this point forward!!  Apparently, the default shape of a newly created turtle allows line drawing and text drawing in a normal fashion.  Now that I understand the concept of a turtle, I solved the problem by creating TWO turtles, one for line and text drawing and one for the arrow!!  Problem solved!!  Again, thank you so much for your invaluable help.

Answer (score 0):

After you've done the arrow at an angle you should do `tg.stamp()` if you want the arrow to rotate while writing it, you should create another turtle and have it written.